# MonoTouch Custom UISwitch color

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, uiswitch

I'm trying to set custom color for `UISwitch`. But thre is only background method:( Im wanna set custom color for "On" state.

Is it possible without subclassing `UISwitch` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* be able to do

```
UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = UIColor.Orange;
```

Notes:

- I say *should* because there's a bug (in 5.0.3/5.1.1) in `UISwitch` where the *setter* is presently missing (only the *get* is present). I'll fix this for future releases of MonoTouch.
- The name is `OnTintColor` since it applies to the colour used when the switch is **ON** only. Most other UI elements use the `TintColor` name.
- As @Joannes said the `UIAppearance` API is available only for iOS5 and later;

Comment: can you give as an ETA ? or this there an workaround until if will be available

Comment: 5.0.4 will be the next maintenance (stable) release and will include this fix. I don't have an exact date but they are never very far from each others (i.e. every few weeks).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about MonoTouch specifically, but the Objective-C API for UISwitch exposes a property called tintColor. Be aware that it will only have an effect in iOS 5 and later.